# From Ukraine to Russia visa

Tags: visas, russia, ukraine, egyptian-citizens

I'm an Egyptian student and I'm travelling to the Ukraine next July. I wanted to ask if I can enter Russia with the same visa or it's not allowed?

Also, I need to know the easiest transportation.

Answer (score 5):

Ukraine and Russia are separate countries with a somewhat hostile relationship at the moment. You need separate visas.

It is possible you are conflating Ukraine with Belarus. Belarus, which is in a customs union with Russia already and has an authoritarian political system, is [close to an agreement](http://eng.belta.by/politics/view/belarus-russia-almost-agree-on-mutual-visa-recognition-109936-2018/) with Russia to establish a system where one visa works for both. This does not appear to be in place yet.

Comment: The OP also asks about transportation, so you should probably mention that Ukraine has no direct flights there. Also, "a somewhat hostile relationship" is war, with mass murders, kidnapping, and partial occupation. So a traveler should be warned against visiting zones of occupation: Donets'k, Luhans'k, and Crimea regions.

Comment: @bytebuster True, although AFAICT, there is still direct train service between Ukraine and Russia; also air service triangulated through Minsk, Belarus.

Comment: Yep, the direct train transportation still infamously exists, though transportation question should be a separate question, imho, as the title mentions only visa.

Comment: Traveling from Belarus to Russia using any form of ground transportation has been and remains illegal if you do not have Russian or Belarusian citizenship.

Comment: @SamJones I guess that excludes international trains.

Comment: @alamar you need a Russian visa to buy a ticket

Comment: @SamJones I don't think so, since you can buy it online. You would need a visa to board. Still it should let you enter Russia by the ground after traversing Belarus.

Comment: @alamar yes you're also checked when boarding, if you try buy in person you must show a visa too. Driving across is illegal but you are rarely stopped, if you are though you can be fined around $3000. My grandfather was from Belarus(was Poland when he was born) so been a few times even though my last name suggest otherwise.